# Is it possible and/or good practice to install packages using Apache Ant or Maven?

Tags: maven, ant, build

I the process of refining our build, it became apparent that we could simplify new deployments a great deal by making ant do most of the setup work. You checkout the code, run a bootstrap task that does things like downloading library dependencies, fetching build-tool binaries etc.

This is not the reason we use ant, but could be a benefit; right now it does things like unit testing, coverage logging, SLOC counting, mess-detection, standards compliance, and so forth.

One step that would also help greatly, is being able to make that bootstrap check for and install OS-package dependencies. Something like:

```
1) Check OS
2) If recognized/supported, run (eg) 
    for Ubuntu: apt-get install curl apache2 libapache2-mod-php5; 
    for RedHat: run yum install -y apache curl-bin
```

Is there a way to do this? I know you can run arbitrary commands, but sudoing breaks that. Also, is there a reason this shouldn't be done even if it could be?

Answer (score 3):

I use Chef to install things and Ant to run builds. You CAN [execute arbitrary commands with Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) but you probably don't want to.

Comment: This makes sense for production and staging, but I'm thinking of cases like: onboarding new devs, re-installing the OS on my dev machine, etc; mostly where puppeting/cheffing is not viable.

Comment: Do you also avoid composer calls in phing/ant, opting instead for puppet or Chef?

Comment: @BryanAgee Puppet/Chef it completely viable for onboarding new devs, I do it regularly. Shove Vagrant on their box and provision it up. Provisioning tools like Puppet and Chef are designed to abstract the exact work you're describing, so trying to do this in Maven/Ant is probably not the best idea. :)

Comment: 1.) Server and Software setup: Chef/Puppet. 2.) Build preperation: Ant (I use Phing because I'm a PHPer. 3.) Deployment: Maybe chef again. All of these tools can do bits and pieces that the others can do, but trying to use one for all is often not that fun.

Answer (score 0):

Ant also provides some of what you are looking for using the `<condition>` task, like below:

```
<target name="run" depends="if_unix, if_windows"/>

<target name="checkos">
    <condition property="isWindows">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="isLinux">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
    <echo message="running on windows"/>
</target>

<target name="if_unix" depends="checkos" if="isLinux">
    <echo message="running on linux"/>
</target>
```

Then you are left with how to determine which version of Linux you are running on.  Sorry, can't help with that part. Once you figure that part out, you can use Ant's `<exec>` task to  execute the system command for either Ubuntu or RedHat.

I am certainly not a Linux admin so I can't speak to whether that's a bad idea or not, but from a build perspective - it sounds reasonable, but once the build has been run once, the installs will be there.  I guess if you really 'bootstrapping' the machine every time, then maybe the Chef approach makes more sense.